# Clarification Needed about Topological Invariants

Tags: ab-initio-calculations, topological-insulators

I am seeking clarification on whether choosing the appropriate topological invariants has any relation to the dimensionality of the system. I understand that in three-dimensional (3D) materials, the Chern number and Z2 invariant are commonly used, while in two-dimensional (2D) materials, the Chern number is often calculated. However, I am uncertain about the specific topological invariant that should be considered for one-dimensional (1D) systems.

Could someone provide guidance on which topological invariant we should calculate for 1D materials to determine their topological nature? Specifically, any available codes that could help with that. Thank you in advance.